# Passing functions/classes to ajax-loaded DOM elements in jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

Ok, I have written some classes/functions that allow me to bind specific behaviors to certain DOM elements. I want to group all the behaviors for certain elements together, so I create a plugin/function that uses delegate to set up all the functionality I want. As an example, say I want all of my forms to pass through a validation check before submitting, and I also want some text to appear when someone exists an input field (these are just examples). So I've written my own form plugin to automatically handle all these capabilities. It might look something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.myFormPlugin = function(options){
    this.each(function(){
        $(this).submit(function(event){
            blah blah blah...
        });

        $(this).children("input").bind("focus",function(){
            blah blah blah...
        });
    });
}
```

And then when the page loads, I simply invoke it via:

```
$("form.mySpecialForm").myFormPlugin();
```

All that works great. But now say I am loading some of these forms via Ajax. How can I automatically bind the plugin to all forms, whether loaded normally or via ajax? I don't believe I can use bind, delegate or live as these can't be associated with a "load" event, so I am stuck. I suppose I could call the plugin as part of the success callback in the ajax load, but then I would have to do that individually with each ajax load.

And I have other plugins to use in a similar way for other DOM elements, like tabs, accordions, etc., so I am looking for something of a holistic approach.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom events - and then trigger those custom events when you need to.

a walk through example: http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/